# How to assign a value to a string variable, that includes embedded '=' in the value

Tags: terraform, format, escaping, special-characters, modifier

With a value such as:

> s = "https://xxx.yyy.com/oauth2/v1/token?grant_type=client_zzzz"

Terraform complains, when try to escape the embedded `=`.  Seemingly, it has no issue, with certain other special chars, such as `?`.

Aside from direct escape `(\)`, I also tried `format()`, with various modifiers. No luck....

If I just use the native format to assign, it renders the value as: `&#061`

---

used a direct escape `\=`, within the string, and, also the `format""%s", var)`.

Comment: What does *Terraform complains* mean? I'm guessing that you get some kind of error message - if so, that **complete, exact** error message should be included in your post so that we have the information it contains available.

Comment: Your question should include the actual Terraform code resulting in the error, and include the actual error message.

Answer (score 0):

```
s = replace("https://xxx.yyy.com/oauth2/v1/token?grant_type=client_zzzz", "=", "&#061")
```

This will replace all occurrences of '=' with '&#061' in your string 's'. You can use similar approach for other special characters as well.

Comment: The original attempt was to simply escape the '=' in the value, such as:
 Error: Invalid escape sequence
│ 
s    = "https://xx.yyy.com/oauth2/v1/token?grant_type\=client_zzzzz"
│
│ The symbol "=" is not a valid escape sequence selector.

Comment: And, my intent is to end up with the actual '=', in the value of the string, rather than replace it with '&#61'...

Comment: With the replace suggestion, it still renders `&#061`, which messes up the query string.